# should I complain to my boss about work partner?

Tags: management, work-environment, colleagues

I  am doing job at a company where my boss divide work between me and one of my other partner.

My partner sits idle whole the day and did not even help me out with the given task. When task is completed, he always tries to take the credit from me and put his name first in front of boss to give himself a better reputation than me.

Should I complain to my boss about this?

Comment: sir  that you had mentioned before is your senior co worker but I am not facing problem with any senior worker?

Comment: and also sir if first vote is negative how can able to solve my problem?

Comment: Regarding the question I marked as duplicate, all the answers propose ways to deal with the situation that doesn't care wether your colleague is senior to you or not. I encourage you to read them. If you question receives downvotes, you should probably edit it in order to have it suit better the guidelines of this site. I invite you to read [Help center](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/help) section.

Comment: How is the task being completed if the work was divided between you and your partner and your partner sits idle the whole day?  Don't do your partner's work for him.

Comment: @Aserre I don't really see this as a duplicate. Very much related, but this is asking about when 1 task is assigned to 2 people and one person is not doing the work.

Comment: @SaggingRufus the answers of the linked question are still on point imo. The key argument is that you should address the issue directly with the manager, which fits either situations

Answer (score 12):

I wouldn't run to your boss and say "Jim isn't doing his work".

Instead, before you both start working on the task, send out an email dividing the work. Do your share of the work and wait. When the deadline gets closer (not too close to the deadline, but close enough that it should be done), tell your boss that the deadline may not be met because you are waiting on some work to be completed.

If he asks which work is not complete, bring up the email where you divided the work, and show your boss exactly which parts are not completed. The best thing you can do in these situations is not to make it about the person, but make it about the work.

Be factual. Ensure you have left a reasonable amount of time for the work to be complete. People all work at different speeds. As long as you left enough time, and you aren't outright blaming someone, you should be fine. Once you start pointing out specific people aren't working, you kind of look petty. If you just point out that X is not complete, then it's completely about work and factual.

From your perspective, you shouldn't care (or in some cases know) why the work is not complete, and it's not your job to care why. It is however your concern that the task be completed on time, hence why you should only mention the work and not the person.

Answer (score -2):

If you feel you are out of your depth in terms of what is required of you technically or otherwise (leaving your co-worker to pick up the pieces), I think you making the first step and recognising this is key, so kudos to you for being honest with yourself!

It seems to me, from the little detail you shared, like your co-worker is a lot more calm and collected about the shared tasks so it may be worth consulting them and asking if they can share any strategies and/or techniques for managing your workload in the way they seem to be successful in doing. The coworker you mentioned may also have some workplace-specific light they can shed on your struggles to help you win back the reputation of your boss, especially if they are held in a higher esteem than yourself. Sounds to me like you have a good attitude though, and trying your best is sometimes all you can do.